# pg_tileserv database connection string specify port

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pg-tileserv

I am trying to connect a DB to pg_tileserv following these directions https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_tileserv/blob/master/README.md

it says after download for windows:

```
SET DATABASE_URL=postgresql://username:password@host/dbname
pg_tileserv.exe
```

but there seems to be no option to pass in the port. I have to connect to another port that is not 5432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just add it after host. Your string becomes

```
postgresql://username:password@host:port/dbname
```

Tileserv (and Featureserv) both use PostgreSQL standard connections URIs

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING